# Determine if Hashset contains object

Tags: java, set

Is there a more effective way from time complexity perspective to check if `HashSet` not contains `object` with given values rather than `set.stream.noneMatch`? 
Currently implemented code for reference:

```
HashSet<Node> set = new HashSet<>(); // set initialization


Node(int x, int y) { // object constructor
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

if (checkSet(node, set)) { //method call
    neighbors.add(node);
}

private boolean checkSet(Node node, Set<Node> set) { // checkSet method
    return set.stream().noneMatch(n -> (n.x == node.x && n.y == node.y));
}
```

So basically I check if there is an `object` with the same values in a `HashSet`.

Comment: Define `equals` and `hashCode` for `Node` and use `contains()` instead of a stream?

Comment: @GriffeyDog Unless there is more to `Node` (object identity or other values). In which case it'll need something like a `Map<NodeKey,Set<Node>>`, or better a third party library multi-map.